# How was Christmas celebrated in early Byzantium?

Tags: middle-ages, christianity, byzantine-empire, early-medieval, christmas

I haven't been able to find any information regarding Christmas in Eastern Rome from before the tenth century. Literally any information regarding the celebration of Christmas in the fifth and sixth century would be useful.

Comment: Googling the two keys words in your question (Christmas, Byzantium) produces several promising-looking results on the first page. Perhaps you could have a look at some of these and then edit your question...

Comment: @LarsBosteen Thanks for answering, but unofrtunately all the links I could see referred to the tenth century onward. I'mtrying to find information from the early Byzantine period.

Comment: You might have more luck searching "Christmas Late Antiquity". which produces some brief sources, one of them mentioning that while established as December 25th by Constantine in the 4th century, it wasn't classified as a major feast until the 9th.

Comment: google 'john chrisostom christmas'. You will find his Xmas sermons, besides discussions about when/how it started.